# GIT push with SSH

Tags: github, ssh, push

I am having create difficulty finding reliable information on creating SSH keys in order to remove the need for username and password when doing git push and pull for a main repo and separate nested repos.

To make sure I have no existing errors deleted them from
https://github.com/settings/keys
And then followed [this guide](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) which in a nutshell advises:

Check for existing, I deleted all from here as well

```
ls -al ~/.ssh
```

then (accepting defaults with no passkey)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and pasting key at https://github.com/settings/keys

[The guide](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) seems to end here, however attempt to push the repo gives:

```
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

What steps have been missed here please.

Attempting to push via git bash

Comment: when username is asked in the last line, did you provide it?

Comment: well yes and then it asks for password - I thought ssh removed the need for this

Comment: For the first time you will have to provide :D

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi-WqFKYpnw try this video, if you are stuck

Comment: That video demonstrates exactly what I did. I don't mean to be critical but it stops short of showing a push

Comment: It should work :) . i followed this video when i first setup the repo using ssh. BTW<  after giving the pass, what happens.